# Invoke client side MS Word - VS2008/C#3.0

Tags: c#

I have a asp.net web site. I want to invoke MS word on a Client machine. Is there any easy way to do this with VS2008, C#3.0?

I can do this with Qt and with an ActiveX control but trying to avoid going this way...

would silverlight be a way to go?

Answer (score 2):

You want to execute an application from the browser (without the evil ActiveX things, of course)?! If you could do that, probably you could wipe off the whole disk too.

And no, Silverlight runs in a partially trusted sandbox. It won't run unmanaged executables on the client machine.

Comment: Well, it's not that wishful. Unpatched versions of IE are out there ;) You could exploit them of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get Word open to view a document, you could just give your user a link to the .doc/.docx file and their browser would take care of opening the file.  If you want to interact with Word, you're going to have a hard time doing that from the browser without using ActiveX.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight has the same locked down sandbox environment that the web browser has, so that won't help you get around this security limitation.

What are you trying to do with Word? Even if you could launch the app, I don't think you could do any kind of COM interaction from within your web page.

An easy way to merely launch Word would be to have the user download a Word file, but I don't think that's what you're asking and they might not open the file -- they could choose to save it instead.

Comment: I have some template that I want to run and create a word document of some mail merge templates and scripts. If i do it on server side, I would run into licensing issues and memory issues. I rather run the template scripts on the client machines and take that work load off my servers

Comment: Can't you just host some MSWord templates (possibly with VBA macros that do the job)?